# how to send parameters in future class

Tags: api, http, parameters, dart, flutter

i want to consume a web service that require headers, body and parameters in future class 
but the problem it shows an error "the named parameters isn't defined'

```
Future<http.Response> postLogin(String login, String password, String jwt) async{

  final response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull('$baseurl/mobile/login'),

    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json ; charset=utf-8',
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader :'Bearer $jwt',
    },

    body: bodyLoginToJson(login, password, token),
    parameters: {
    token, login
    }
  );
```

can someone help please

Comment: [`http.post`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) has named parameters `headers`, `body`, and `encoding`.  There is no parameter named "`parameters`".  Perhaps you intend to pass it as part of the `body` `Map`?  It's hard to tell without knowing more information about what the web service exactly expects.

Comment: when i test the web service in postman i fill in the params and it works, and it doesn't work when i put them in body

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @jamesdlin, `parameters` is not a named parameter of the http class. The standard way of posting values using dart / flutter is a map past to the `body` parameter. Don't assume the terminology used in postman will be the same in dart.

```
    Map<String, String> _headers = {
      "Accept":"application/json"
    };
    var response = await http.post(LOGIN_URL, headers: _headers, body: {
      "username": username,
      "password": password,
      // whatever other key values you want to post.
    }).then((dynamic res) {
      // ... Do something with the result.
    });
```